# turkish characters in php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, turkish

I'm currently working on a php sql based translation database and am having issues getting the 6 distinct Turkish characters into sql.

the page is set to a utf charset and I have tried using utf8_encode to no effect, I am also using Cyrillic on the page so am stuck having it all in utf8.

at the moment I am just trying to pass the value from a form via post and then echoing it out, but that is also failing.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit*

managed to get it to output in an echo with htmlentities, unfortunately it is now not entering sql properly. the field is set to utf8_unicode_ci

update code is below

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
mysql_query("UPDATE turkish='$turkish'  WHERE tid='$tid'");
```

Comment: Post some code, or a link to a demo page.

Comment: @jon have added the relevant lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing updates do it this way:

```
mysql_query( "UPDATE turkish = _utf8'$turkish'  WHERE tid='$tid'" );
```

don't use utf8_encode or anything similar just make sure $turkish contains valid utf-8 data.

and when reading:

```
SELECT tid, BINARY turkish, ...
```